# How to find the Average of column values in a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to print out the average of values in each column of a 2D Array. I've already figured out how to find the average across a row, but I am still struggling with doing that down a column.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 for ( i=0; i<nRow; ++i)
    {
        for( j=0; j<nCol+1; ++j)
        {
            if (j == nCol)
            {
                nAve = (float)nSum/nCol;
                printf("=%.1f", nAve);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d\t", aArray[i][j]);
                nSum += aArray[i][j];
            }
        }

        nSum = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: swap the for loops without changing the inner code

Comment: what you expect? i think your code is correct.

Comment: Maybe the first nSum initialization ? Despite that I would avoid doing a +1 inside the second for loop. It's a bad habit imo

Comment: Why does `i` range [0..nRow-1] while `j` ranges [0..nCol]? It looks like one of your loops does not have correct range.

Comment: For brevity consider rewriting, "I need a code that prints out the average and column of a 2DArray." You're asking for two (2) things: 1. The average and 2. The column. What exactly do you mean by, "the column"? The average of the columns? The column value? The column index?

Comment: i need the average of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier is to do another for to count the column average.
Like :

```
for ( j=0; j<nCol+1; ++j)
    {
        for( i=0; i<nRow+1; ++i)
        {
        }
    }
```

If you want to do it with one for you should create an array to keep and increase the total of all column.

```
float sumColumn[nCol];

for ( i=0; i<nRow; ++i)
    {
        for( j=0; j<nCol+1; ++j)
        {
            if (j == nCol)
            {
                nAve = (float)nSum/nCol;
                printf("=%.1f", nAve);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d\t", aArray[i][j]);
                nSum += aArray[i][j];
                sumColumn[j] += aArray[i][j];
            }
        }

        nSum = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
```

In the sumColumn array you will have the sum of all column at the end.